# RetrieveMultipleRequest & Service.Retrievemultiple - When and Why?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

As the title suggests,

When and why would we use RetrieveMultipleRequest over Service.Retrievemultiple?

Can I please get one or two scenarios where one would be more preferable to the other?

My understanding is that RetrieveMultipleRequest is similar to doing a FetchXML query (and can in fact use FetchXML instead of a queryexpression).

Is this the reason? If so, what can you do in a FetchXML query you can't do in a QueryExpression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [CRM 3.0 docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa680899.aspx),

> CrmService (*IOrganizationService in CRM 2011*) contains a set of methods common to many entities.

So the `RetrieveMultiple` method of the `IOrganizationService` interface is a shortcut method for the `RetrieveMultipleRequest` and `RetrieveMultipleResponse` action pairs. This is best seen when looking at the [documentation for the `RetriveMultipleRequest` class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrievemultiplerequest.aspx): the documented example references the `IOrganizationService`'s `RetrieveMultiple` method, *not* the `RetrieveMultipleRequest` or the `RetrieveMultipleResponse` classes, which would also suggest Microsoft intends the two to be interchangeable.

Because they are interchangeable, you *can* pass `FetchXml` to the `RetrieveMultiple` method. See [Anwar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182570/684271) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9182200/684271) to see how and why you'd use `FetchXml`.

Answer (score 1):

RetrieveMultiple method creates instance of RetrieveMultipleRequest class and sends it to server. No special purpose to use RetrieveMultipleClass directly.