# Should I use queryexpression or FetchXML for complicated Dynamics CRM 365 project?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml, query-expressions

I need to transfer a CRM 4.0 "project" to CRM 365. I have already transferred the data and create all forms.

The main "program" in 4.0 is a .dll plugin involve few sql in it, each sql includes multiple "group by", "join". There is an update sql query as well. The .dll includes a complicated customized "view" from sql server. Then this .dll would call a report rdl, in the rdl there are more sql and call a stored procedure. Finally a report would be generated.

I need to do this fast so plan to do all of these in a asp.net program. I think I can either use queryexpression or FetchXML. But look like queryexpression  doesn't support "group by" that kind of aggregate functions so it looks like FetchXML is easier. But FetchXML seem like has no debug at all.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QueryExpression vs. FetchXml CRM2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182200/queryexpression-vs-fetchxml-crm2011)

Comment: Honestly its a matter of preference